Whats the best way to design an event table where different event items are provided each time the event updated
I have a raw event table that I'm working with. It has two columns date and metadata. Metadata has raw json dump of all the event attributes. But I'd like to make it clear that each time different attributes are sent. And then I need to ingest this data into looker.
Raw table:



timestamp
metadata




2024-04-1
{"type":"created","title":"test1","due":"2024-04-02","id":12345}


2024-04-1
{"type":"confirmed","id":12345}


2024-04-1
{"type":"completed","id":12345, "completedby":"johndoe"}



Now I need to normalize it
OPTION A :



timestamp
type
title
due_date
id
completed_by




2024-04-1
created
test1
2024-04-02
12345



2024-04-1
confirmed


12345



2024-04-1
completed



johndoe



OPTION B:



timestamp
type
title
due_date
id
completed_by




2024-04-1
created
test1
2024-04-02
12345
johndoe


2024-04-1
confirmed
test1
2024-04-02
12345
johndoe


2024-04-1
completed
test1
2024-04-02
12345
johndoe



How should I design the table, should I fill all the rows with their respective information (Option B) or should I leave them as nulls (Option A)?

Option B allows you to get all the information for a type.

I'm not sure I understand the raw table: are the created, confirmed and completed types different events? as in: john doe created something in one moment in time, then confirmed, and finally completed? do you want to treat these as different events?

@AleixCC, yup the idea here is that Johndoe conducted different actions in that day (he first created a task, confirmed it, and then completed it) - so I thought to treat them as different events to show the types of actions made.

Option B is what I would aim for, specially because it holds relevant information for all rows, which would make it easier for reporting purposes.
Also, given that you want to treat the different actions (created, confirmed, completed) as "sub-events", one thing you could do on top of option B is to also add a surrogate key based on the id, the type and the timestamp. See an example below using the dbt_utils package:
{{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['id', 'type', 'timestamp']) }} as sub_event
This way, you can have a primary key in your model to define the granularity, as well as e.g. easily count "sub-events" for each user.
